# Using Swagger with Flask alone

Tags: python, api, rest, flask

I have discovered Swagger to generate the doc for a Restful Api I've developing, but the issue is that I'm using Flask alone not flask-restful and when I try to use the flask-restful-swagger wrapper it's not working, for example something like this :

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import create_session
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from Model import *
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_restful_swagger import swagger  

app = Flask(__name__)
api = swagger.docs(Api(app), apiVersion='0.1', api_spec_url="/api/spec")
session = create_session(bind=engine)


@app.route('/employees/', methods=['GET'])
@swagger.operation(
   parameters=[
      {
         "name": "body",
         "description": "Get the employees in the shop.",
         "required": True,
         "allowMultiple": False,
         "dataType": NsEmployee.__name__,
         "paramType": "body"
      }
    ],

   responseMessages=[
      {
          "code": 201,
          "message": "Created. The URL of the created blueprint should appear in the Location header"
      },
      {
          "code": 405,
          "message": "Invalid input"
      }
])

def employees():
   if request.method == 'GET':
     # do something...        

   return jsonify(json_results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

But when I try to get `/api/spec/` I obtain **Not Found**. My question is there is any way to avoid the use of flask-restful-swagger and integrate Swagger only with Flask.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Give a try to flasgger :  https://github.com/rochacbruno/flasgger may be the best 'lite' library for adding Swagger on a vanilla Flask project.

Answer (score 7):

I'm personally using a "Swagger-first" approach with Flask, i.e. writing the Swagger API (YAML) before implementing operations. This approach is very nicely supported by the Connexion library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/connexion (I'm one of the authors)

Connexion does not use flask-restful and gives you "automatic" validation and type mapping (according to Swagger spec).

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/gangverk/flask-swagger

It supports both MethodView classes (like Flask-RESTful uses) and vanilla flask methods